# Use a google font and include only [A-Z] and '&'

Tags: webfonts, google-webfonts, google-font-api

Is there a way to use a google font and have it load only `[A-Z]` and the `&` ampersand character?

I would like to do this to reduce size and improve load time, since I will only use basic latin numbers and letters.

I can host the font myself if I must and it is legal to manipulate the font package, but am not sure if self-hosting is necessary and how to manipulate google's font package.

I have specified `A-Z` like this:

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata&text=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

but specifying `&` is troublesome. Both of these don't work:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata&text=ABC&amp;' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata&text=ABC&' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is no way to specify character ranges when including google fonts. The only way to do it is to specify each character like this:

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata&text=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Comment: And if you only need to style the header, you can load even fewer characters: `http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata&text=MyHeader`

Answer (score 21):

[You can include special characters by url-encoding their UTF-8 representation.](https://fonts.googleblog.com/2011/04/streamline-your-web-font-requests.html)

**&** (U+0026) is `26` in UTF-8, so your url should have:

```
&text=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ%26
```

Here's a handy tool for this:
http://www.url-encode-decode.com/